# i have come across a strange error in nodejs filesystem

Tags: node.js

i am working with the filesystem protocol of nodejs. i did writing the file, reading the file and now trying to rename it. it actually renames the file but throws me this error and my localhost stops running.

this is the error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:690
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('chunk', ['string', 'Buffer'], chunk);
```

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

```
file1: var fs = require('fs');

// write

function write(fileName, content) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(`./test/${fileName}`, content, function (err, done) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(done);
            // console.log('file created >>', done);
        });
    })

}

function readFile(fileName, cb) {
    fs.readFile(`./test/${fileName}`, 'utf-8', function (err, done) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
            return;
        }
        cb(null, done);
    })
    }

function rename(oldname, newname, cb){
    fs.rename(`./bands/${oldname}`, `./bands/${newname}`, function(err,done){
        if(err){
            cb(err)
            return
        }
        cb(null,done)
    })
}
rename('pinkfloyd.txt', 'tool.txt', function(err, done){
    if(err){
        console.log('error in renaming')
    }
    else{
        console.log('renamed>>')
    }
})

readFile('kisor.txt', function(err,done){
    if(err){
        console.log("error in file reading >>",err);
    }else{
        console.log('success >>',done);
    }
})

write('kisor.txt', 'i am javascript')
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log('write success ', data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error in wirte >>', err);
    })
// objec short hand
module.exports = {
    write, readFile, rename
}



i have imported the exported stuff from file 1 here in this file:
//var { write,readFile, } = require('./file');// object destruct
var fileOp = require('./file1');
//console.log('file operation >>', fileOp);
fileOp.write('brodway.txt', 'i am infosys of  nepal')
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log('done >>>', data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('err',err);
    })

fileOp.readFile('kisor.txt',function(err,done){
    if(err){
        console.log('err',err);
    }else{
        console.log('success >>',done);
    }

and lastly, here is the server:

var http = require('http');
var fileOp = require('./file1');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // this function will be executed whenever a client is connected
    // request or 1st argument is http request object
    // response or 2nd argument is http response object
    var url = request.url;
    if (url == '/write') {
        fileOp.write('abcd.js', 'hi')
            .then(function (data) {
                response.end('data', data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                response.end(err);
            })
    } else if (url == '/read') {
        fileOp.readFile('abcd.js', function (err, done) {
            if (err) {
                response.end(err);
            } else {
                response.end('done' + done);
            }
        })
    } else if(url == '/rename'){
        fileOp.rename('pinkfloyd.txt', 'tool.txt', function(err, done){
            if(err){
                response.end(err)
            }
            else{
                response.end('done', done)
            }
        })

    } else {
        response.end('form default page');
    }

    console.log('client connected to server');
    console.log('request url >>', request.url);
    // request response cycle must be completed
    // response.end('hi from node server'); response cannot sent more than once

});

server.listen(8080, function (err, done) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('server listening failed');
    }
    else {
        console.log('server listening at port 8080');
        console.log('press CTRL + C to exit from server');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem in response.end(err). In this code err is object, but must be string or buffer.

Answer (score 2):

In this section of code:

```
    fileOp.rename('pinkfloyd.txt', 'tool.txt', function(err, done){
        if(err){
            response.end(err)
        }
        else{
            response.end('done', done)
        }
```

You are calling `response.end('done', done)`.  But, the `fs.rename()` callback does not have a `done` argument - it only has the `err` argument because there's no data to communicate back - the rename either succeeded or it didn't .  So, `done` will be `undefined`.  So you're calling:

```
 response.end('done', undefined);
```

The function signature for `response.end()` is this:

```
 response.end([data[, encoding]][, callback])
```

So, you're trying to send `undefined` for the encoding.  That is not correct.

---

Your rename function should be change from this:

```
function rename(oldname, newname, cb){
    fs.rename(`./bands/${oldname}`, `./bands/${newname}`, function(err,done){
        if(err){
            cb(err)
            return
        }
        cb(null,done)
    })
}
```

to this:

```
function rename(oldname, newname, cb){
    fs.rename(`./bands/${oldname}`, `./bands/${newname}`, function(err){
        if(err){
            cb(err);
            return
        }
        cb(null);    // no 2nd argument here
    })
}
```

or even simpler:

```
function rename(oldname, newname, cb){
    fs.rename(`./bands/${oldname}`, `./bands/${newname}`, cb);
}
```

---

FYI, it appears you're using `.end()` improperly a bunch of places in your code where you do this:

```
response.end('done', someData);
```

That's not how it works.  You aren't emitting an event.  You're commanding the end of the http response and you need to follow this function signature:

```
response.end([data[, encoding]][, callback])
```

So, you'd probably just do `response.end(data)`, if `data` was a string.

Comment: @AR - You posted a lot of code.  I've pointed out several things wrong with your code.  You need to fix all of those.  Can you apply those fixes and then reduce the problem down to one simple function or a lot smaller set of code that causes it?  FYI, node.js also has built-in promises for the `fs` module now, so you don't have to reinvent all that yourself.

Comment: @AR - The error implies that you're trying to send data that is supposed to be a String or a Buffer, but it's neither of those.  Look in your code where that could be happening.  Reducing your code down to smaller sets of code to isolate which piece of code is causing this error.  This is basic debugging.

Comment: @AR - Also, why are you doing `response.end('data', data);` in a bunch of places?  That's wrong.

Comment: And, 'tried, didn't work' is just rude.  I've pointed out multiple errors in your code.  They are clear coding errors.  You need to fix them all - everywhere they occur.  Maybe there are still more errors, I can't tell because I don't have a runnable version of your code that I could personally debug.  A more proper response might be.  Thanks for pointing out all those errors.  I'll go through my code and apply those fixes everywhere and then see what happens.

Comment: @AR - Most of your file methods have the same problem I document for `rename()`.  You need to fix them all.  And, stop using `response.end()` improperly.

Comment: sorry, im just in a bad mood, been trying to fix this for the past 5 hours now, i feel dumb.

Comment: @AR - Well being rude to the people trying to help you doesn't make me want to pour over your pages of code to find more errors.  Since you may be new here, the procedure now would be that you would apply the above fixes to all the places the problems occur in your code and you would retest.  If the same problem still occurs, then you add a new section of code to your  answer (preserve the original block of code - don't edit that) and you post a comment addressed to me indicating that you've added a new revision of the code based on the advice and are still having the same problem.

Comment: @AR - If you want to solve it yourself, you break your code down into the smallest chunk that exhibits the problem until you find the one piece of code causing the problem.  For example, if you change all occurrences of `response.end()` to just `response.end('done')`, does the problem go away?  I'm going offline for awhile.  Good luck.